# Creating WebApi with custom headers and form-data

Tags: rest, header, asp.net-web-api2, postman, form-data

I am new to WebApi development. I have already created a `GET` request with `Basic Authentication`. Now I want to create a `POST` method while passing some `custom headers` and `form-data`. Below is the sample screenshot of Postman

**Header Section**

[image]

**Body Section**

[image]

**Update 1**

I am doing the following

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Route ("aux_relay_operations/[controller]")]
    public HttpResponseMessage RelayMethod(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var value = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["test"];

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, value);
    }
```

**Postman**

[image]

I have added a debug point on the above method but It's not going inside it.

I must be doing something wrong.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: The question in unclear to me, what you're trying to achieve and what issues are you facing?

Answer (score 1):

Your route appears to be defined wrong, getting a 404 is indicative of that.
You can't check anything with regards to the actual data being sent yet.

I imagine (from what you have written and your postman URL) that it should be:

```
[Route("aux_relay_operations/[action]")]
```

Having `[controller]` in your route means it's probably expecting the controller name.
As a first change though, I would make the route this, and see if it works:

```
[Route("aux_relay_operations/RelayMethod")]
```